# How to add the values of two “Cards” in Java?

Tags: java, blackjack

I am working on a project to simulate the first deal in a game of blackjack. So far, the program creates two cards of random rank (such as 2 or 3) with a random suit. I am struggling with creating a **switch table or if-else ladder** to assign the added value of the two cards as the variable "score". The professor created a java .class where each card rank is assigned an integer value (Two is the 0th card so it has a value of 0, Three is the 1st card so it has a value of 1). My problem is to create a Score() method to calculate the *actual* added score of the two cards.

```
if (card1.rank() == 0){
        score = 2;            
    } else if (card1.rank() == 1){ //I need the program to examine both card1 and card2
        score = 3;
    } else if (card1.rank() == 2){
        score = 4;
```

I only know how to assign a new value to *one* of the cards, how can I alter this code so that it takes the values of *both* cards and returns the correct score instead of just one of the cards? Thanks so much for the help, I will do my best to quickly answer any questions to clarify.

Comment: I don't understand what the rank has to do with the score at all.  Why are you even looking at ranks in this case?  You just want to add all the different card scores together, don't you?

Answer (score 1):

Get the score of `card1`, then get the score of `card2` and then add those respective values together (addition) and that is your cumulative score.

```
int score = getScore(card1) + getScore(card2);
```

Where `getScore(Card)` is the `switch` or `if else` chain you refer to. **Or**, you might choose to make `getScore()` a part of the `Card` class and then use it like

```
int score = card1.getScore() + card2.getScore();
```

**Edit**

```
return card1.getRank() + card2.getRank() + 4;
```

Score for one card is `rank() + 2`. Score for two cards is `card1.rank() + 2` plus `card2.rank() + 2`, or `card1.getRank() + card2.getRank() + 4`.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but I can't create a new method to getScore(). I can only work within the Score() method that already exists to write an if/else or switch to calculate the score for a two-card hand and to return the value.

Comment: @JamesCurtis `card.rank()` looks like an `int` in your post. If it's not, how are you doing the `== 1` and `== 2`?

Comment: Yes, card.rank() is an int. However, the .rank() of the card is not the same as the .score() of the card.

Comment: `card1.rank() + card2.rank() + 4` would work, but only for the integer cards. The face cards have a rank() of Jack = 9, Queen = 10, King = 11,and Ace = 12.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your approach. Using an integer to represent the rank of a card is fine, but using 0=deuce...12=ace makes things too complicated. Much better would be 1=ace, 2=deuce,...13=king.

For example, with your way, the score of a single card would be something like:

```
int cardValue() {
    if (this.rank == 12) return 1;
    if (this.rank >= 8) return 10;
    return this.rank + 2;
}
```

My way, this becomes:

```
int cardValue() {
    if (this.rank >= 10) return 10;
    return this.rank;
}
```

Your `Score()` function is out in the middle of nowhere. Where does it fit within your object structure? It can't be a method of Card, because that should return just the score of one card. What object represents a Hand of cards? That would be one place for the Score() method. If you have no hand object but just use a list of cards, then maybe Score() could be a static method of Card, but it would take a list of cards as an argument. Finally, Score() has no way to indicate hard/soft hands. A score of soft 17 is different from a score of hard 17 (for example, some casinos hit one but not the other).

Let's say you have a Hand object with an array of cards called `cards`. Here's one way:

```
int handTotal() {
    int total = 0;
    boolean foundAce = false;

    for (Card c: this.cards) {
        total += c.cardValue();
        if (c.cardValue() == 1) foundAce = true;
    }
    if (foundAce && total < 12) total += 10;
    return total;
}
```